# i m getting  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while trying to run a ndk example?

Tags: android, android-ndk

i m just trying to run ndk example code from below link.
[How do I handle calls to AudioTrack from jni without crashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560748/how-do-i-handle-calls-to-audiotrack-from-jni-without-crashing)

But getting the above exception.The below is the detailed log.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15523): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
E/AndroidRuntime(15523): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: audioFunc
E/AndroidRuntime(15523):        at com.audio.demo.MainActivity.audioFunc(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15523):        at com.audio.demo.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(15523):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
W/ActivityManager( 2486):   Force finishing activity com.audio.demo/.MainActivity
```

i m stucked with this exception can anybody help me?